# How to change value of a vector in a Refcell

Tags: rust

```
pub enum Chain {
    Node(Rc<Node>),
    Nil,
}

use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::rc::Rc;

pub struct Node {
     pub block: String,
     pub parent: Chain,
     pub children: RefCell< Vec<Chain>>,
 }



fn add_child(&self, chain: &Chain, s: &String) {
    match chain {
        Chain::Nil => {}
        Chain::Node( n) => {
            let new_node = Node { block: s.clone(), parent: Chain::Node(Rc::clone(n)), children: RefCell::new(Vec::new()) };
            let new_child=Chain::Node(Rc::new(new_node));
            let old_children= n.children.into_inner();
            let mut new_children : Vec<Chain>= Vec::new();
            new_children.extend(old_children.iter());
            new_children.push(new_child);
            n.children.replace(new_children);

        }
    }
}
```

error message

> expected `&Chain`, found enum `Chain
> In add_child,

I want to add a new child to node.

I know how to change the value of a cell ref if i create this value from scratch. (cellref.replace(newValue)).
But I am creating the newValue from the old value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Borrow it as mutable and add the element:

```
n.children.borrow_mut().push(new_child);
```